# How can I replace the dot between the numbers in a caption with a dash?

Tags: captions

How can I replace the dot with a dash between the numbers -- only in captions not in chapters or sections? i.e., replace 1.1 with 1-1 in this command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{book}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx} ‎‎‎
‎\usepackage{caption}‎‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\chapter{one}‎
‎\section{one}‎
This is the image ‎\ref{a}‎.\\
(This is the image ‎1-1)‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎\begin{center}‎
‎\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}‎
‎\captionof{figure}{a}\label{a}‎
‎\end{center}‎
‎\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the instruction

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}
```

to the preamble. This will leave the appearance of section numbers (1.1., 1.2, etc) unchanged.